# Remover espaçamento criado entre imagem e div

Tags: css, css3, sass

Gostaria de entender porque é criado um espaçamento entre a imagem e a div? Como é possível ver ao adicionar o background vermelho. E como corrigir sem utilizar `position` ou `margin` e `padding` negativos?

```css
.box-img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  
  // tentando remover padding
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.box-img > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  // tentando remover margin
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<figure class="box-img">
  <img src="http://img1.topimagens.com/ti/th/200x200/lobos/lobos_068.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
```

Comment: Vale lembrar também que não existe uma propriedade chamada _marging_, para definir as margens utilizamos a propriedade _margin_

Comment: @Ademílson erro de digitação! Valeu por corrigir! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta apenas acrescentar o posicionamento da imagem:

Utilize este css para a `.box-img > img`:

```
.box-img > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Simplificando, apenas adicione esta linha de código em `.box-img > img`:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Valeu @Bruno Rigolon. Mas eu acabei descobrindo que adicionando um display: block; na imagem tenho o mesmo resultado que vertical-align: middle;. ;)

Comment: Perfeito @alan. Mas recomendaria a trabalhar com o vertical-align. Se você tem o costume de utilizar algum framework CSS, exemplo bootstrap, por padrão eles setam: img {vertical-align: middle}. Exatamente para evitar este tipo de comportamento e praticamente 99% dos casos, o vertical-align como middle é o que esperamos.

Comment: Valeu pela dica. Já estou adicionando no meu reset o img {vertical-align: middle}! :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso adicionando uma altura para a div PAI (*.box-img*)

```
.box-img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Para o que estou fazendo a div pai não pode ter um altura fixa.

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução que encontrei foi adicionar um `display: block;` na imagem!

```css
.box-img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  
  // tentando remover padding
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.box-img > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  
  // tentando remover margin
  marging: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<figure class="box-img">
  <img src="http://img1.topimagens.com/ti/th/200x200/lobos/lobos_068.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
```